# How to prevent pdflatex to stop working due to an invalid input file?

Tags: pdftex

I want to create a LaTeX editor.

Behind the scene, the editor will call `pdflatex.exe`.

I need a method to prevent `pdflatex.exe` to stop working because of an invalid input file.

Is there anybody here knows the protocols, rules, conventions used by `pdflatex.exe` ?

Note: I created the question [in StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5210950/how-to-detect-an-application-executed-by-a-process-whether-the-application-stops) as well.

### Edit

Using suggestions from @Martin and @arx (a SO member), my actual problem is solved. THANK you!

Comment: Normally you call `(pdf)latex` with `-interaction=nonstopmode` (or what the MikTeX equivalent is). Then it will not stop on errors. Your editor can detect compile errors by watching the return value of the `pdflatex` subprocess and by locking on the "console" or log output.

Comment: Another way would be to look if `pdflatex` wants to read from standard input, i.e. waits for user input.

Comment: To complete Martin's comment, there is also the `-halt-on-error` option in pdfTeX, LuaTeX and XeTeX.

Comment: It would be good if we resolve this question here somehow so that it doesn't stay "unanswered" forever. I added my comments as answer. Maybe you should post your solution here as well. One of them should then be accepted. I don't mind either way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Normally you call (pdf)latex with -interaction=nonstopmode (or what the MikTeX equivalent is). Then it will not stop on errors. Your editor can detect compile errors by watching the return value of the pdflatex subprocess and by locking on the "console" or log output.

Another way would be to look if pdflatex wants to read from standard input, i.e. waits for user input.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to passing `-interaction=nonstopmode` is to prepend `\nonstopmode` to the document. I think it has the same effect, but doesn't require altering the `pdflatex` invocation.